# robots.txt query string disallow except for one case

Tags: robots.txt, url-parameters

I can't find solution for my task.

For example, I have 2 pages: `/` and `/some-category/`. Both of them have GET parameters: `page` and several filters.

I need the result: `/`, `/?page=x`, `/some-category/` to be allowed, and `/?page=x&`, `/some-category/?` to be disallowed.

I found this: `Disallow: /*?*`. It prevents crawling for any query strings on the website, and it's good, but what should I supplement to get the desired result?

Comment: robots.txt is probably not the right tool for the job here.   It doesn't support regular expressions, so it isn't really expressive enough for your cases.   Are you willing to change your URLs to make them more compatible with robots.txt?   Are you willing to try other solutions such as redirects or canonical tags?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yeah, I already use robots meta tag. OK, so I'll remove the GET parameter "page" and create another route for this. Then "Disallow: /*?*" will fit me perfectly. Thank you.